# How to use different sets of validation rules and be able to change it in before_validation?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Let's say I have a model with some validaton rules:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country


  validates :company_name,
            :presence => {
                :if => :name_empty?,
                :message => 'field required'
            },
            :length => {
                :maximum => 255,
                :too_long => 'max field length is %{count}'
            }
  validates :firstname,
            :presence => {
                :if => :company_name_empty?,
                :message => 'field required'
            },
            :length => {
                :maximum => 64,
                :too_long => 'max field length is %{count}'
            }
  validates :lastname,
            :presence => {
                :if => :company_name_empty?,
                :message => 'field required'
            },
            :length => {
                :maximum => 64,
                :too_long => 'max field length is %{count}'
            }

end
```

and for some conditions I'd like to change those rules completely - use different set of rules. How can I do this? Conditional validation and grouping didn't work for me (maybe because I have some ":if" in my rules already). In CakePHP I'd change validation rules in beforeValidate() and pass new array of rules to model, but I don't know how to do similar thing in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use some custom condition methods - `:if => :name_empty?` calls `@customer.name_empty?` (where `@customer` is an instance of this class) to determine whether to perform the validation or not. Your code example lacks definitions for these methods, but they can be as complex as you like.

If you mean that you want to change for example the `:maximum` option for the length validator based on some condition you can simply define another validator on the same attribute.

```
validates :firstname, length: { maximum: 64, if: :normal_user? }
validates :firstname, length: { maximum: 666, if: :satan? }
```

If there are only two possible values you could even use the same method:

```
validates :firstname, length: { maximum: 64, if: :normal_user? }
validates :firstname, length: { maximum: 666, unless: :normal_user? }
```

The validation will be then performed always, just the maximum value will change.

If you use the first example the validations will be performed if `@customer.normal_user? || @customer.satan?`. In the case where both these methods return false the validation will not be performed.

**NOTE: I am not sure what will happen if both the methods return true, so there's something for you to check and watch out for. I suspect it will work as expected though. **

You probably have already read this, but as this question may be read by someone else, here's a little something on [(conditional) validations in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation). Definition of the `validates` method is also worth reading on the [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What if i'd like to remove some validation rules in before_validate? Is it possible?

Comment: In my opinion `before_validate`isn't really a place for that. You would have to use some sort of a variable that tells the validator to not fire. I think it would be easier and cleaner to just use the method I showed. You can disable validations alltogether by doing `@customer.save(validate: false)`

You can probably meddle with the validators set on the class, as they can be accessed with a class method `Customer.validators`, but I don't recommend that. You can quickly get it too complicated to maintain and validation rules should be as clean and simple as possible.

Comment: If you do try to meddle with that - remember to also write a comprehensive set of tests for the model, to ensure the validations behave how you actually want them to.

Maybe if you gave an example, so that I could understand what you can do in `before_validate` that you can't in the condition method, I could give a more accurate answer.

Just make sure you need that level of complexity there and you aren't overthinking it. Simple is better ;)